# Can I gain entry to the US with a damaged ePassport chip, under the new rules (post-April 2016)?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

As per the title really. I am travelling to the US on Saturday (I know, a little late to be asking this!) and I am concerned that I will have problems on arrival due to my passport chip not working.

As I have an ePassport I can apply for an ESTA, and I have read other comments regarding the fact that the ESTA requirements only state that the passport needs a chip, not that it has to be working, but these don't seem to be related to experience with the new system implemented in April 2016. Does anyone have specific experience with the post-April 2016 system?

I am travelling to Miami International.

Comment: I have read that, but due to it being asked right at the start of April 2016 (when the new regulations were introduced) it seems as though the responses are from people with experience of the old system, not the new one. As we are now 8/9 months into the new system, I am hoping that some more relevant information can be given.

Comment: In that case perhaps you should ask explicitly for the experiences of travelers who have used the VWP after April 2016 with a passport chip that they know to be broken.

Comment: I added a bounty on the other question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Thanks @Vince! I closed this so we can focus on that one.